# Create a view without a defined el property with events - Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've been trying to learn Backbone, and I'm developing an app now. But I have a problem with a view's events: App.views.ChannelView should have a click event, but it is not firing.
Here's the code: 
http://pastebin.com/GgvVHvtj

Everything get rendered fine, but events won't fire. Setting the `el` property in the view will work, but I can't use it, and I've seen on [Backbone's todo tutorial](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/todos.html) that it is possible.
How do I make events fire without a defined el property?

Comment: Don't include a link to your code, include a minimal functional example of your code in your question. Why can't you use the view's `el`? What makes you think that the Todos tutorial is using an `el`-less view? A cursory check suggests that all the views in there have `el`s.

Comment: @muistooshort Not really. Check TodoView on the example. It only uses tagName. I'm gonna edit my question and add the functional example.

Comment: But do you know what `tagName` does? The [`el` documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) is pretty clear on this.

Comment: I do know that. But I can't use a predefined el property.

Comment: Then use the usual properties to get the view to build one or [specify the `el` when you create the view](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor).

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work.

Comment: (1) Include a minimal demo of your problem in your question. (2) Provide a minimal yet functional demo at jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com. Make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define the el element to be an existing element in your DOM. If you do not define it, fine, it will default to a div, but when you render the view, the html generated must be appended/prepended whatever, you get the point, to an existing DOM element.
Events are scoped to the view, so something's wrong with your scope. From the code you provided I can't reproduce the problem, so if you might, please provide a live example on jsfiddle/jsbin etc in order to fully understand the issue.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7bMoQ6?p=preview)** ( in order to demonstrate the view render )

```
var App = {
    collections: {},
    models: {},
    views: {},
};

App.models.Channel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '#jucaSaoBoizinhos'
    }
});
App.views.ChannelView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$('#PlaceHolder'),
    events: {
        "click .channel": "myhandler"
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html('<div class="channel"><button>' + this.model.get('name') + '</button></div>');
        return this;
    },
    myhandler: function(e) {
        alert(e);
        console.log(this.model.get('name'));
    },
});

var chView = new App.views.ChannelView({model: new App.models.Channel()});
//console.log(chView.render().el) //prints div#PlaceHolder
//without the el specified in the view it would print a div container
//but i would have to render the view into an existing DOM element
//like this 
//$('#PlaceHolder').html(chView.render().el)
chView.render()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing a

```
events: {
  "all": "log"
}

log: function(e) {
  console.log e;
}
```

That should log out every event that's getting fired. I find it super helpful when troubleshooting.

Comment: Really? Even if you say click on something in your view (like a button) it doesn't log a click event?

Comment: Yep, nothing. I have no idea what's wrong with my view, it just has no events.

Comment: Here's a thought - do you know for sure that your view is actually initialized? What happens if you add an initialize function to your view that just logs out "initialized!". Curious if that's even called.

Answer (score 0):

backbone view events can work without dom element specified. If you can't use any element at the view createion (initialization) moment, then you can use it's 'setElement' method, to attach your view to specified dom element. [Here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) is description.

Be the way your view render method will not work also without specified 'el'.

Comment: I'm setting the el on initialization now,but it still doesnt have any events

Comment: have you checked view el property in console after view init? is it defined?

Comment: Yeah,it is. I did console.log(this.el) and it was defined.

Comment: is view rendered to your element? is it have child with class 'channel'?